# how hide button work in angular js....?

Tags: angularjs

Actually I want to hide my navigation bar by clicking on hide button.
there are two buttons 1st one hide and another is show.. when I click on hide it should be hide my navigation bar and vice versa.

Comment: Please refer below links: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide and https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-ngshow-and-nghide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the flag variable in the controller and use it on html with ng-show.
Add a function in the controller to set the true/false and invoke it when user will click on button.

Comment: Thank you very much it's working....